# In which cases the outer Lebesgue measure is additive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In which cases the outer Lebesgue measure is additive?

it is known that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ holds for disjoint bounded closed sets.

1) is it true for any disjoint closed sets?

2) is it true for $A$ - bounded and closed, and $B$ disjoint with $A$ (but not closed)?

3) is it true for disjoint open sets?

There is a well-known result states that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ holds for sets having positive distance between them.

If $A$ - any, $B$ - countable, then also $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ holds.

are there any other general cases when the outer Lebesgue measure is additive?

Comment: It holds for any disjoint, measurable sets.

Comment: It applies when $A,B$ are measurable and their intersection has measure zero. You can give many sufficient conditions for this, but (per some complicated machinery with set theory) we know that none of them are necessary. The necessary and sufficient condition can really only be stated in terms of measurability.